How to refresh datatable in child lwc without wire method when data is passed from aura component
I have an LWC component that serves as a child component within an Aura comopnent. I'm passing data from Aura to the LWC to display in a Data Table. There is a button in the LWC, and when clicked, it updates data in the backend. I'm attempting to pass an event from the LWC to Aura to trigger an update in the child LWC data, but the data is not updating as expected.
Below is the code which I am trying
Aura Code
<aura:attribute name="lstFeeDetails" type="List" access="public" /> <!-- Added on 21/4/2020 lstFeeDetails-->

<c:iFB_ReversalOfChargeDetailCase aura:id="childTransactionDetailCmps" reversalOfChargeOnCaseData = "{!v.lstFeeDetails}" totalAmount="{!v.decTotalChargeRev}" caseId="{!v.recordId}" oneventToDetailCaseCmpToUpdateDataTable = "{!c.eventToDetailCaseCmpToUpdateDataTable}"/>

eventToDetailCaseCmpToUpdateDataTable: function(component, event, helper) {
        var caserecordId= event.getParam('casdId')
        var action = component.get("c.fetchTransactionDetailRecord");
        action.setParams({
            strCaseId:caserecordId
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state == "SUCCESS") {
                var result = response.getReturnValue()
                console.log('custAuthList is'+JSON.stringify(result));
                component.set("v.lstFeeDetails",JSON.stringify(result));
            }       
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }

LWC JS
columns = [
                {
                    label: '',
                    type: 'button',
                    typeAttributes: {
                        title:'CBS',
                        variant:'destructive',
                        alternativeText:'Delete',
                        name:'CBS',
                        label:'CBS',
                        disabled: { fieldName : 'IFB_Is_CBS_Callout_Sucess__c' }
                    },
                    cellAttributes: {
                        width:'3rem'
                    }
                },

                {
                    label: '',
                    type: 'button',
                    typeAttributes: {
                        title:'PE',
                        variant:'destructive',
                        alternativeText:'Delete',
                        name:'PE',
                        label:'PE',
                        disabled: { fieldName : 'IFB_Is_PE_CallOut_Fail__c' }
                    },
                    cellAttributes: {
                        width:'3rem'
                    }
                },
            ];
connectedCallback() {
        console.log('erer',this.reversalOfChargeOnCaseData);
        this.data = this.reversalOfChargeOnCaseData;
        this.totalAmount = this.totalAmount;
        this.caseId = this.caseId;
    }

LWC HTML
<lightning-datatable
                data={data}
                columns={columns}
                onrowaction={handleRowAction} 
                key-field="id"
                hide-checkbox-column>
            </lightning-datatable>```

Is there anyother way to update the data in Child LWC?
